# Best approach for automatically increasing data in React/Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Let's say I have a UI element and I want it to bind to a state in redux store. It's a good approach when this state change is triggered by user operation. But what if this is a state that keep changing by itself? For example if an element needs to display how long the page has been opened. If the page dispatch an action every 100ms then it's going to a huge memory leak because every 100ms there has to be a new state object create and stored and never garbage collected.

I currently just use good old jQuery to update it but I think it would be nice if this data binding can be integrated into the big react/redux flow. Any suggestions are welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Redux only stores older states in memory if you are using the Redux DevTools, and that has a default limit on how many older states are stored.  In production, no older states are stored, and everything will be garbage collected.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-state-memory .

Comment: @markerikson Thank you, it's good to know, I didn't know this before. So I assume you suggest the best approach for this problem is to bind the UI element to a state and not to worry about the memory?

Comment: Ah... basically, yeah, don't worry about the memory aspect.  Also, I would actually suggest that you not think in terms of the word "binding" when using React and Redux.

Comment: @markerikson Thanks you. Could you elaborate what's the problem of the word "binding"?  Also what if the tree is big, every very short of time the state tree has to be replicated, seems to me it's going to make the browser spend a lot of cpu times on GC.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer my own question.
It's helpful to look at [this](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287#issuecomment-176330134) and [this](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1303) and [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html).

In this case the best way imo is to bypass redux store and render a new UI element with new props. This way only the props in relavant to the display of the UI element is replicated instead of the complete state tree.

Rendering a new UI element will not remove the old UI element because that's what react is good at: comparing the difference and only update the part that needs to be updated.